# Let $|G|=2^n3$. Show that there's a normal subgroup of order $2^n$ or $2^{n-1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

> Let $|G|=2^n3$. Show that there's a normal subgroup of order $2^n$ or $2^{n-1}$.

What I did so far:

I used the third Sylow theorem, which says that if $|G|=p^nb$ with $\operatorname{GCD}\{p,b\} = 1$ then the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups, $n_p$, divides $b$ and $n_p \equiv 1 \operatorname{mod}p$. From here, we have that $n_2 = 1$ or $n_2 = 3$. If $n_2 = 1$, then the $2$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is normal and the order is $2^n$. If $n_2 = 3$ then I need to show somehow that there's a normal subgroup of order $2^{n-1}$.

Any hints on how to continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Assume $n_2=3$. Let $Syl_2(G)$ be the set of $2$-Sylow subgroups. Define an action of $G$ on $Syl_2(G)$ by conjugation, i.e $g.P=gPg^{-1}$. This action induces a homomorphism $\varphi:G\to S_{Syl_2(G)}\cong S_3$. Can you show $\varphi$ is surjective? If so, can you finish the exercise?

Comment: I think I've got it. Here it is: $\varphi$ is surjective because every $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is conjugate to each other. Then, $G/\operatorname{ker}\varphi \simeq S_3$, and we have $|G/\operatorname{ker}\varphi| = 6$. Thus, $\operatorname{ker}\varphi \triangleleft G$ and $|\operatorname{ker}\varphi| = 2^{n-1}$. Is it correct?

Comment: It's not quite enough to say that the Sylow subgroups are conjugate to each other.  That doesn't show that $\varphi$ is surjective because its image could be a $3$-cycle within $S_3$.  So you're not quite done.

Comment: @whatsgoingon You are almost there. Indeed, the image of $\varphi$ has to be transitive. However, why can't the image be the subgroup $\{id, (123), (132)\}\leq S_3$? This is also a transitive subgroup of $S_3$. Do you see why this can't be the image?

Comment: @Mark We have $|G/\operatorname{ker}\varphi| = 1,2,3$ or $6$ and $\operatorname{ker}\varphi \subseteq N_G(S)$, where $N_G(S)$ denotes the normalizer of a $2$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ (I'd have to prove this claim because I'm not sure about it). So, we either have $|\operatorname{ker}\varphi| = 2^n$ or $2^{n-1}$. We know $|G/\operatorname{ker}\varphi|$ can't be $3$ because there's no normal $2$-Sylow subgroup. Thus, $|\operatorname{Im}(\varphi)| = 6$ and $\operatorname{Im}(\varphi)=S_3$. Does this work?

Comment: @whatsgoingon The kernel is indeed the intersection of the normalizers, but you don't really need it. As we already said before, the image is a transitive subgroup of $S_3$, and so it must be of size either $3$ or $6$. And you explained correctly why it can't be of size $3$. So that's it.